# Laravel 5.1 Authentication views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.1 and the modular package.
In my controller I use the following login method:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{   
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $password = $request->input('password');

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
       return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
   }

   return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
   'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.']);
}
```

My route:

```
Route::group(array('module' => 'Admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'), function() {

Route::get('admin/dashboard', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
]);
}}
```

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view("Admin::index");
}
```

My Middleware/Authenticate:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
     if ($this->auth->guest()) {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
             return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
         } else {
             return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
         }
     }

     return $next($request);
 }
```

This works and redirects me to the index view after login.
When the user is not logged in, it is still possible to access the index view by accessing the url: localhost/admin/dashboard.

How can I redirect the user to a custom page which shows an error to the user that it is not possible to access the url localhost/admin/dashboard when he is not logged in?

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    The issue is with your route the middleware should be at the top level as soon as you hit the controller it should redirect if not authenticated

    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth','module' => 'Admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'], function()
    {
        Route::get('admin/dashboard', ['uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
    });

secondly if you want to redirect user to a custom page you can do this 

public function redirectUnAuthenticateUser()
{

\Session::flash('login_error', 'Kindly login before you can access this page');
//create a view that user would be redirected to
return view('session.unauthenticated') ;
}


and the change your auth function to below 

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
     if ($this->auth->guest()) {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
             return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
         } else {
return redirect()->route('you-custom-rout-name-matching-above-function');
         }
     }

     return $next($request);
 }

and on your view you can get the value of the flash message
```